# xml parser does not report any error message

Tags: tcl

While using `dom`  package I have notaiced, that when some attributes are enlcosed with the `“`  instead of `"`, then no error message is reported and all such attributes are ignored.

How to report such errors?

Comment: Is this TclDOM? If so, you can report errors here http://sourceforge.net/p/tclxml/bugs/ Be sure you set the category to "TclDOM".

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a small sample of the input and code.